# when i open bootstrap modal it gets pop up from that position where it was closed

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have around 16 fields in my bootstrap modal.When I save the form and re-open it the modal pop ups the same position where it was closed.I want to open a new modal from it's original position.Please help me

Comment: @Oleg please help

Comment: So you want to reset the form or is it something else?? And please provide code to elaborate more.

Comment: No,I don't want to clear the form ,as I am doing that before opening it. The problem which I am facing is , the position at which the form is closed it re-opens from that same position.I want my modal to open scrolled from the top.For that I am using this $("#modal-content").scrollTop(0) but this is also not working. Any suggestion @ShalinPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this.After some RND,this piece of code worked fine for me
$('#modalId > div.modal-dialog').scrollTop(0);